# Why does my RSA signing implementation work on some messages, but not on others?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, digital-signature

I am trying to implement a simple RSA signature algorithm in C#, by only using BigInteger, and no built-in crypto tools. To sign a message, I encrypt it with the private key, and to verify it, I decrypt it with the public key. In the code below, I have noticed a very strange behavior. For some input strings, (e.g. "Test"), it successfully validates the signature, but for other strings (e.g. "Test1"), it fails.

What I've noticed is, that it only fails, when the `m` variable (the hash of the message) is a negative number, and this causes the decrypted `ver` variable to become an extremely large number and the code prints 'Wrong Signature'.

```
// Generating RSA keys
var random = new Random();
var p = new BigInteger(256, 100, random);
var q = new BigInteger(256, 100, random);

var n = p.Multiply(q);
var phi = p.Subtract(BigInteger.One).Multiply(q.Subtract(BigInteger.One));

var e = new BigInteger("65537");
var d = e.ModInverse(phi);

// Preparing the message
var messageHash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test"));
var m = new BigInteger(messageHash);

// Signing the message
var signature = m.ModPow(d, n);

// Verifying the message
var ver = signature.ModPow(e, n);

Console.Out.WriteLine(m);
Console.Out.WriteLine(ver);

if(ver.Equals(m))
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Valid Signature");
else
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Wrong Signature");
```

I'm using BouncyCastle for the `BigInteger` type.

Example output for the message "Test":

```
16928957987407306249184430693954511195  
16928957987407306249184430693954511195  
Valid Signature
```

Example output for the message "Test1":

```
-40249184872970767997805928798048797124
10061048024793920770364189111057222210443355984675629704584018449091407182950576678391694061743052292040531884029654111183675927763342349593675935744009443
Wrong Signature
```

I believe that the error is somewhere in the signing process, and not in the verification. Maybe I shouldn't try to encrypt negative numbers? What should I do if the hash is negative? How can I fix this code so it works reliably on any input string?

Comment: The RSA algorithm requires `0 <= m < n` for a message `m` and modulus `n`, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Encryption) .
To prevent negative numbers, `var m = new BigInteger(1, messageHash);` could be used, which creates the corresponding unsigned value instead of the signed value.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks, you've solved my problem. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Be aware that "Textbook" RSA, where signing and verifying are the same operations as encryption and decryption isn't safe, and isn't used in real systems.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Actually there is a wole suite of professional software from a very big and reputable company that uses this exact algorithm for verifying license keys. For obvoius reasons, I won't mention their name here, but you can trust me, I've seen it.

Answer (score 0):

@Topaco helped me solve my problem.

> The RSA algorithm requires 0 <= m < n for a message m and modulus n, here . To prevent negative numbers, var m = new BigInteger(1, messageHash); could be used, which creates the corresponding unsigned value instead of the signed value